# Unable to create folder in .nsf file with unicode characters

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I'm using Interop.Domino.dll with lotus notes 8.5 following code in c# .net:
I am creating new folder in Lotus Notes client. The folder name is having some unicode characters. If try to I set the name I am getting error as

> ""Notes error: Name too long
>   (DifferentlanguagesÜðĂþÖÖ~VV¶ñíćšŽšäâÎ¤ø˙Ÿœ€…„∏ĆıœšŽÞÚ)"

The folder name limit of lotus notes is 64 character but this string is having 54 characters

Here is my code

```
NotesSeesion LotusNotesSession=new NoteSession();
LotusNotesSession.Initialize(null);
NotesDatabase Database=LotusNotesSession.GetDatabase("",FilePath,false);
Database.EnableFolder("DifferentlanguagesÜðĂþÖÖ~VV¶ñíćšŽšäâÎ¤ø˙Ÿœ€…„∏ĆıœšŽÞ);
```

> //Exception "Notes error: Name too long
>   (DifferentlanguagesÜðĂþÖÖ~VV¶ñíćšŽšäâÎ¤ø˙Ÿœ€…„∏ĆıœšŽÞÚ)"

Answer (score 3):

The folder name limit of Lotus Notes is maybe 64 *bytes* and the folder name gets encoded in UTF-8, which results in 89 bytes for your string.

This happens frequently when programmers don't really pay attention to what they're doing or documenting. My guess is that this limit predates Unicode support in Lotus Notes and back when things were interpreted in a single-byte codepage it held true, but eventually UTF-8 was used to introduce Unicode support at that point, which reduces the number of available characters in a somewhat unpredictable manner.

Comment: You are mostly right in your conclusion about documentation frequently ignoring the difference between bytes and characters, but Lotus Notes is actually not storing UTF-8 - or any other form of Unicode. Development on Lotus Notes was started before Unicode was adopted, and they have stuck with something called LMBCS as their internal character set. The various APIs do automatic convsersions from Uniode and other platform character sets, so you don't really notice it - until something goes wrong.

Comment: LMBCS documentation is very hard to find  nowadyas. (It was never easy to find, to tell the truth.) So a few years ago, I created a reference database that lists the LMBCS values for all Unicode characters and I posted it on the OpenNTF site. chttp://openntf.org/Projects/codebin/codebin.nsf/CodeByDate/CE6B55B6B4A04A6E862576E10008B911

Comment: That link does not work unfortunately... Should be chttp://openntf.org/Projects/codebin/codebin.nsf/CodeSearch/CE6B55B6B4A04A6E862576E10008B911

Comment: It still doesn't work!  Trying again!  http://openntf.org/Projects/codebin/codebin.nsf/CodeByDate/CE6B55B6B4A04A6E862576E10008B911